# UIView changing its position in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

How do I make a `UIView` slide up with a touch of a button from its original position and them bring it back down with a touch of a button? Using Swift and Xcode 6.

I have currently tried this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var DynView: UIView!

@IBAction func btnUp(sender: AnyObject) {

}
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You have to implement an animation changing the `DynView` position on click. Here's an example:

```
@IBAction func btnUp(sender: AnyObject) {
    let xPosition = DynView.frame.origin.x
    let yPosition = DynView.frame.origin.y - 20 // Slide Up - 20px

    let width = DynView.frame.size.width
    let height = DynView.frame.size.height

    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: {
        dynView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: yPosition, width: width, height: height)
    })
}
```

Comment: OK OK.. I see now Thiago.. just one more thing its giving me a error: !CGRect is not converitble to UIView

Comment: Try dynView.frame = CGRectMake(xPosition, yPosition, height, width)

Comment: //Derdida thanks it took the error off but when i ran the app and gave a click to my up button it crashes and in my appdelegate im recieving "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" to consideration i have an up and down button in this view

Comment: never mind guys i got it.. it was just a simple syntax error.. thanks for everything thiago and Derdida!!!!!

Comment: hey guys just one more thing.. we made it possible to move the view up and down using the buttons, but now i don't want the bottom of the view to move as i touch the up button. i want it to stay in its position as a default.. in general all i want is the top of the view to move..

Comment: Yeah i made a little mistake and forgot to add ".frame"

Comment: About your last comment, try to increase the height of the view by the same value you add to your yPosition. Please check as accepted answer or upvote if it solved your problem :).

Comment: hey guys thanks for the help yesterday. today i need a little more help.. how can i program the button so that i can only click it 3 times and make it go up a position with every click... example first click up moves the view +80, second click +100 more.. and from there i can go no further.. the same thing goes for the down button.. any suggestions.

Comment: Don't forget to disable "Auto-Layout" if you want it to work.

Answer (score 10):

Hi create this extends if you want. **For Swift**

**Create File Extends.Swift** and **add** this code

```
/**
    Extension UIView
    by DaRk-_-D0G
*/
extension UIView {
    /**
    Set x Position

    :param: x CGFloat
    by DaRk-_-D0G
    */
    func setX(#x:CGFloat) {
        var frame:CGRect = self.frame
        frame.origin.x = x
        self.frame = frame
    }
    /**
    Set y Position

    :param: y CGFloat
    by DaRk-_-D0G
    */
    func setY(#y:CGFloat) {
        var frame:CGRect = self.frame
        frame.origin.y = y
        self.frame = frame
    }
    /**
    Set Width

    :param: width CGFloat
    by DaRk-_-D0G
    */
    func setWidth(#width:CGFloat) {
        var frame:CGRect = self.frame
        frame.size.width = width
        self.frame = frame
    }
    /**
    Set Height

    :param: height CGFloat
    by DaRk-_-D0G
    */
    func setHeight(#height:CGFloat) {
        var frame:CGRect = self.frame
        frame.size.height = height
        self.frame = frame
    }
}
```

**For Use (inherits Of UIView)**

```
inheritsOfUIView.setX(x: 100)
button.setX(x: 100)
view.setY(y: 100)
```

Answer (score 7):

I kinda combined the two most voted answers into one and updated to Swift 3. So basically created an extension that animates a view moving to a different position:

```
extension UIView {

    func slideX(x:CGFloat) {

        let yPosition = self.frame.origin.y

        let height = self.frame.height
        let width = self.frame.width

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {

            self.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: yPosition, width: width, height: height)

        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 // MARK: - Properties

var bottomViewHeight: CGFloat = 200
var isViewHide = false

private let bottomView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .red
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()

private let showHideButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.setTitle("Show / Hide", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showHideButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()

// MARK: - Lifecycle

override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()

    view.addSubview(bottomView)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        bottomView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: bottomViewHeight),
        bottomView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
        bottomView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
        bottomView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
    ])

    view.addSubview(showHideButton)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        showHideButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
        showHideButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
        showHideButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerXAnchor),
        showHideButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerYAnchor)
    ])

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    showHideView(isShow: isViewHide)

}

// MARK: - Selectors

@objc func showHideButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print(" HIDE / SHOW BUTTON")

    showHideView(isShow: isViewHide)

}

// MARK: - Functions

private func showHideView(isShow: Bool) {
    if isShow {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
            self.bottomView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: self.bottomViewHeight)
        }
    } else {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
            self.bottomView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
        }
    }

    isViewHide = !isViewHide

}
```