# How to add a large image to UISlider background or place within scrollview?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, customization, uislider

I'm trying to build the image below but I'm unsure of whether to put a `UISlider` within a `UIScrollview`, OR skip that entirely and sup up the slider. The columns need to move horizontally and change color with each movement.

[image]

Comment: I'm going to try creating the UIView with gesture recognizer, it just seems overcomplicated.

Answer (score 1):

***Swift5***

```
a simple way to  make this is, 
1. take a view container
2. You should use pan gesture recogniser to the timer view.
3. them add vertical lines with grey color.
4. as you move the timer view change the color of the line to orange.

Suggested readings: PanGesture recogniser, View transform.
```

Comment: Perhaps use UIViews for the vertical lines? The problem, however, is that the lines alpha on the outskirts, but darken as the user moves the timer view. And it's not limited to just those lines. It's all hours of the day. Hence my suggesting a horizontal scrollview. Additionally, the timer view has to stay in the same place.

Comment: yes, you will use UIView for lines and to adjust the colour you can use alpha property e.g 0.2, 0.4 0.6. you will find how to faint the alpha with respect to the co-ordinates of view by studying the tranformation property. it is my personal view that you dont need to use scrollView for this.

Comment: If not a scrollview, then how does the timer view move? especially since\ it needs to stay in the same place? Just through Pangesture? Then I'd need to treat it like a picker since I'd be scrolling through the same time values

Comment: you can move the view by adding position.x  to the view.centre.x at specific time intervals. Use timer property to add this position with respect to time. Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(runTimedCode), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25694388/uiview-changing-its-position-in-swift/43684348